# Can't connect to AWS RDS MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I am not able to connect to a fresh instance of AWS RDS MySQL

```
mysql -h <host>.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<host>.rds.amazonaws.com' (111)
```

The credentials are correct.

Here are the inbound security rules

[image]

I have even set "Public Accessibility" to "Yes" (which I don't want to) but no luck. Any help? Thanks

EDIT 1:

Output of telnet after rebooting rds instance :

```
telnet host.rds.amazonaws.com 3306 Connecting To
host.rds.amazonaws.com...Could not open connection to the host, on
port 3306: Connect failed
```

Route Table:
[image]

Network ACL:
[image]

Comment: Could you please try `telnet host.rds.amazonaws.com 3306`. That will give you if there is a network problem or auth. I guess, it should be a network problem. So can you also send us your routetable entries (associated with the rds subnet) and NACL entries.

Comment: If you set the public accessibility after you deploy the rds server then you might need to restart your rds server.

Comment: @MuhammetArslan Please check the updated description

Comment: @Lamanus I have rebooted the instance but no luck

Comment: How many subnets do you have and are you sure all of the subnets use the same rt ?

Comment: @MuhammetArslan I have 3 of them and all of them and all of them are associated with the same rt